# tomcat different context path of one webapp based on domain

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, tomcat6, co

I've got one web application, and I want it to be hosted on two different context paths. There is no problem with that

```
<Context docBase="myapp" path="/address1" />
<Context docBase="myapp" path="/address2" />
```

But I want it to be based on domains, for example:

- /address1 for localhost1
- /address2 for localhost2

Also I want this application to be hosted in single instance (not one for /address1 and another for /address2 ).

Comment: Do you want to configure http://localhost1/address1 and http://localhost2/address2 ?

Comment: @pedrofb yeah, just like that